# How to store the data within java application?

Tags: java, database, h2

I am using H2 database which is embedded in my java application. I'm creating the connection to the server as:

```
jdbc:h2:file:/mydata
```

Where mydata is the database name. This seemed to tell the database connection caller to find the database within the same directory as of the application running from. But it cant find it on client computers. Why? What to do? Where to save the database so as to I don't lose data when I distribute my application?

Comment: Do you distribute that file together with your Java application? You'd better use remote standalone database like MySQL

Comment: @Ivan: I don't think that client-server-databases are always better than embedded databases. It depends on the use case. A standalone desktop application may be totally fine with an embedded database and is easier to install (as far you know, what to do :-)

Comment: @vanje agree, but what if several users need to work with the same data/database?

Comment: @Ivan: In this case a server database should be used or better a server application with a service layer which hides the database. As I said, it depends on the use case. Sometimes there is only one user then there is no need for the network connection overhead or managing a second database process.

Comment: @Ivan yes i distribute the some sample data with my application. For mysql either the user need to install a server in his system itself or have to connect to a network. A simple single user standalone application need not do that I suppose.

Comment: @vanje do you have any idea or suggesstion on my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation you do not need `/` before `mydata` you you need to look up for a file in the same directory

> The database URL for connecting to a local database is jdbc:h2:[file:]**[path]**. The prefix file: is optional. If no or only a relative path is used, then the current working directory is used as a starting point. The case sensitivity of the path and database name depend on the operating system, however it is recommended to use lowercase letters only. The database name must be at least three characters long (a limitation of File.createTempFile).

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases

So in your example you are trying to connect to file named `mydata` in the root folder. Looks like you forgot a dot (`.`) before `/mydata`. Try with the following `jdbc:h2:file:./mydata`